# expected value of sample from a skewed distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value, descriptive-statistics, types-of-averages

Let us say a market's prices are distributed with a skew.

Given a sample of 10000 products, I can estimate the median, arithmetic mean and weighted average or any other statistic.

Let us say I draw 100 products from this distribution, what would be their total expected/average value? I cannot use arithmetic mean * 100 or can I? Should I use median * 100? Or should one use 100 * weighted average?

I am sorry I am still confused about this, despite reading lots of related posts here and elsewhere. Any clarification would be very much appreciated please. Thanks!

PS:

Given Dave's answer and code below, I tried to simulate my situation. Basically I assumed a lognormal distribution to get a skew. I obtain some averages from a larger sample. I want to see which average to use to best estimate the total of N randomly sampled items. It turn out that, according to this (correct?) simulation the arithmetic mean is the better average in my situation. I guess this is some empirical evidence against my gut feeling that the median is the better/more representative average in my situation ...

```
p1 <- log(10)
p2 <- log(2)

# obtain estimates/averages from large sample from "the truth"
x <- rlnorm(1000000, p1, p2)
plot(density(x))
median <- median(x)
mean <- mean(x)

set.seed(2021)
N <- 100 # sample size
R <- 10000 # how many times to draw samples of size N
mean_estimate_se <- median_estimate_se <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
    
    x <- rlnorm(N, p1, p2) 
    
    sum <- sum(x)
    
    mean_estimate_se[i] <- ((mean * N) - sum)^2
    median_estimate_se[i] <- ((median * N) - sum)^2
    
}

paste0("Error using arithmetic mean: ", round(mean(mean_estimate_se), 2))
paste0("Error using median: ", round(mean(median_estimate_se), 2))

round(mean(median_estimate_se) / mean(mean_estimate_se), 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether the distribution is skewed or not, the usual sample mean is always an unbiased estimator for the population mean.$^{\dagger}$

$$
\mathbb E\bigg[\bar X\bigg] = \mathbb E\Bigg[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\Bigg]\\
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^n \bigg( \mathbb E[X_i]\bigg) 
=
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \mu = \frac{1}{n}n\mu = \mu
$$

The usual sample mean is a perfectly defendable way to estimate the population mean.

*Should* gets into lots of fascinating ideas related to constructing estimators with desirable properties but might be a bit beyond where you want to operate. Depending on the particulars of the distribution, you might find the median to be a better estimator of the mean, perhaps based on the mean squared errors of those estimators.

$^{\dagger}$There's this annoying issues where the population mean might not exist. In that case, this calculation does not make sense, but you are trying to estimate a value that does not exist, which also does not make sense.

**EDIT**

In your comment, you mention that median might be a preferable estimator for a skewed distribution. Let's put that to the test in a simulation study.

```
set.seed(2021)
N <- 100 # sample size
R <- 1000 # how many times to draw samples of size N
means <- medians <- rep(NA, R)
for (i in 1:R){
    parameter <- 13 # the parameter of the distribution
    x <- rchisq(N, parameter) # this has a mean of parameter
    
    means[i] <- mean(x)
    medians[i] <- median(x)
    
    }

mean((means - parameter)^2)
mean((medians - parameter)^2)
```

I get an MSE of the sample mean of $0.25775941187491$ and an MSE of the sample median of $0.845599781948668$, more than three times as big. For this $\chi^2_3$ distribution, at least in terms of the common MSE metric, the mean is a vastly superior estimator, despite the skewness. As noted in the comments, other distributions, such as $t_3$, will give the opposite conclusion (despite the symmetry of $t_3$).

(I had trouble coming up with a skewed distribution that gave superior performance of the empirical median, and I welcome suggestions in the comments. For superiority of the empirical mean for a distribution that lacks skewness, look no further than the normal distribution. (Noted in the comments, absolute value of a low-degree-of-freedom t-distribution should do the trick.))

Comment: Thank. Think its the cauchy distribution where the arithmetic mean does not exist. Coming back to my use case. The median is more representative in the skewed case and ar. mean would over estimate total expected price. Would it not? So I am still confused why you say this  ...

Comment: Cauchy is one example where the expected value does not exist, yes. // Why do you say that the arithmetic mean overestimates the population mean? It is an unbiased estimator that, on average, returns the right answer.

Comment: If you replace `rchisq(, 13)` by, say, `rt(, 3)` (which has an expectation of zero, a finite variance, and a symmetric distribution to boot), you will draw the opposite conclusion when comparing the sample mean to the median.  Thus, your blanket statement "the mean is a vastly superior estimator" needs qualification.  Indeed, researchers who have run extensive simulation studies have concluded that in many cases robust alternatives to the mean lose relatively little efficiency for near-Normal distributions and often have superior efficiency for less-than-Normal distributions.

Comment: @Dave - thanks. I do not recall saying exactly "mean overestimates the population mean" in this context. IMHO the mean is not representative for this skewed distribution and thus misleading for my use cases: estimate the total expected value of 100 randomly drawn products. So my question is, if I draw 100 hundred products at random from this skewed distribution what would be the expected total of 100 the products. Is a better estimate to use 100*median or 100*arithmetic mean or 100*weighted average or ... ? Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Part 2: I guess drawing 100 products from this distribution 100s of times would result in a normal distribution with a certain mean according to the CLT. The arithmetic mean of this distribution would be an estimate of the population mean but again this does not help me with the expected total value of 100 randomly drawn products or does it? Sorry for being thick ...

Comment: If you want the expected sum of those $100$ values, sure, take $100\bar x$. You can tweak my simulation to estimate the sum of the $100$ observations instead of the mean, and it will reveal that, under the given conditions, sample mean has much lower mean squared error than sample median. // I haven’t though my through exactly how to do this, but there might be a way to use a bootstrap procedure to estimate which is better for your exact data. // Could it be that you don’t want to estimate a mean (expected value) but a median?

Comment: @Dave - thanks. Sorry I am still confused. All I want to know is which statistic to use in my use case to come as close to the expected/average total of let us say 100 observations drawn from my use case's distribution. IMHO the 100 * arithmetic mean would be too large as the distribution is skewed.

Comment: You have to be careful about what exactly you want. If what you want is to estimate the mean (or some multiple of the mean, such as $100\mu$), then there is an argument to use the sample mean. If you want to estimate the median (or some multiple of the median), then a different estimator might be appropriate. So what exactly do you want to estimate?

Comment: Re "superior performance of the empirical median:" take absolute values and use t distributions with small df.

Comment: @Dave - I added some PS to my question inspired by your answer, which I will most likely accept but a quick glance would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're more-or-less following what I am doing, just with log-normal instead of chi-squared, and you're coming to a similar conclusion. // Do note that you might prefer to estimate the median or sum of medians, rather than the mean or sum of means, though that is a decision for you (and a separate question if you are not sure which you want). // Quick note about your code: reconsider naming variables as existing functions like `sum`. I'm surprised that your code even compiled and didn't throw an error when you got to `i=2` and had redefined `sum` to be a number instead of a function.

Comment: @Dave thanks for your comments reg. code. I can see your point but do not think that's an issue and AFIK R is not compiled but simply interpreted. I also think that functions and variables can be seen as distinct - so naming clashes should not be an issue.